# How to Join two IEnumerables with anonymous types?

Tags: c#, linq, concatenation, ienumerable

I'm using Linq-to-Xml to create two `IEnumerables` but I want to combine the results of the second list with the first list. When I use the `.Concat()` I get the following error:

> 'IQueryable<>' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Concat<>(ParallelQuery<>, IEnumerable<>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<>'

The two lists I'm trying to `.Concat()` are here:

```
var findingDetails = from f in element.Elements(ns + "Group")
                     select new
                     {
                         testID = (string)f.Attribute("id").Value,
                         title = (string)f.Element(ns + "title"),
                         idrefFD = (string)f.Element(ns + "Rule").Attribute("id").Value,
                         severity = (string)f.Element(ns + "Rule").Attribute("severity").Value,
                         description = (string)f.Element(ns + "Rule").Element(ns + "description"),
                         fixText = (string)f.Element(ns + "Rule").Element(ns + "fixtext")
                     };
var getStatus = from gs in element.Descendants(ns + "rule-result")
                select new
                {
                    idrefStatus = (string)gs.Attribute("idref").Value,
                    result = (string)gs.Element(ns + "result"),
                    dateTime = (string)gs.Attribute("time")
                };
```

The error is generated on the `findingDetails` usage here:

```
var combined = findingDetails.Concat(getStatus);
```

What I'm trying to get is a `var` with that has everything from `findingDetails` + `getStatus.result` and `getStatus.dateTime`, in one place. This why I only have to iterate over one `foreach()` loop to access all of the values instead of using a nested `foreach()` loop.

Sample XML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<cdf:Benchmark style="SCAP_1.1" resolved="1" id="RHEL_6_STIG" xsi:schemaLocation="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/xccdf-1.1.4.xsd http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0 http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe/2.2/cpe-dictionary_2.2.xsd" xmlns:cdf="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1" xmlns:cpe="http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <cdf:status date="2016-04-22">accepted</cdf:status>
  <cdf:title>Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Security Technical Implementation Guide</cdf:title>
  <cdf:description>The Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Security Technical Implementation Guide (STIG) is published as a tool to improve the security of Department of Defense (DoD) information systems.  Comments or proposed revisions to this document should be sent via e-mail to the following address: disa.stig_spt@mail.mil.</cdf:description>
  <cdf:notice id="terms-of-use"></cdf:notice>
  <cdf:reference href="http://iase.disa.mil">
        <dc:publisher>DISA</dc:publisher>
        <dc:source>STIG.DOD.MIL</dc:source>
  </cdf:reference>
  <cdf:plain-text id="release-info">Release: 11 Benchmark Date: 22 Apr 2016</cdf:plain-text>
  <cdf:platform idref="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:6"></cdf:platform>
  <cdf:version>1</cdf:version>
  <cdf:Profile id="MAC-1_Classified">
        <cdf:title>I - Mission Critical Classified</cdf:title>            
  </cdf:Profile>
  <cdf:Value id="var_umask_for_daemons">
        <cdf:title>daemon umask</cdf:title>
        <cdf:description>Enter umask for daemons</cdf:description>
        <cdf:value>022</cdf:value>
        <cdf:value selector="022">022</cdf:value>
        <cdf:value selector="027">027</cdf:value>
  </cdf:Value>
  <cdf:Group id="V-7055">
        <cdf:title>APPNET0031 No Strong Name Verification</cdf:title>
              <cdf:description>&lt;GroupDescription&gt;&lt;/GroupDescription&gt;</cdf:description>
            <cdf:Rule weight="10.0" id="SV-7438r2_rule" severity="medium">
                  <cdf:version>APPNET0031</cdf:version>
                  <cdf:title>Digital signatures assigned to strongly named assemblies must be verified.</cdf:title>
                  <cdf:description>&lt;VulnDiscussion&gt;A strong name consists of the assembly's identity, simple text name, version number, and culture information (if provided)—plus a public key and a digital signature.  Strong names serve to identify the author of the code.  If digital signatures used to sign strong name assemblies are not verified, any self signed code can be impersonated.  This can lead to a loss of system integrity. &lt;/VulnDiscussion&gt;&lt;FalsePositives&gt;&lt;/FalsePositives&gt;&lt;FalseNegatives&gt;&lt;/FalseNegatives&gt;&lt;Documentable&gt;false&lt;/Documentable&gt;&lt;Mitigations&gt;&lt;/Mitigations&gt;&lt;SeverityOverrideGuidance&gt;&lt;/SeverityOverrideGuidance&gt;&lt;PotentialImpacts&gt;&lt;/PotentialImpacts&gt;&lt;ThirdPartyTools&gt;&lt;/ThirdPartyTools&gt;&lt;MitigationControl&gt;&lt;/MitigationControl&gt;&lt;Responsibility&gt;System Administrator&lt;/Responsibility&gt;&lt;IAControls&gt;DCSL-1&lt;/IAControls&gt;</cdf:description>
                  <cdf:reference>
                        <dc:publisher>DISA</dc:publisher>
                        <dc:identifier>2030</dc:identifier>
                        <dc:type>DPMS Target</dc:type>
                  </cdf:reference>
                  <cdf:fixtext fixref="F-12596r7_fix">Use regedit to remove the values stored in Windows registry key hKLM\Software\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification. There should be no assemblies or hash values listed under this registry key. All assemblies must require strong name verification in a production environment. Strong name assemblies that do not require verification in a development or test environment must have documented approvals from the IAO.</cdf:fixtext>
                  <cdf:fix id="F-12596r7_fix"></cdf:fix>
                  <cdf:check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
                        <cdf:check-content-ref href="U_Microsoft_DotNet_Framework_4_V1R4_STIG_SCAP_1-1_Benchmark-oval.xml" name="oval:mil.disa.fso.dotnet:def:2"></cdf:check-content-ref>
                  </cdf:check>
            </cdf:Rule>
      </cdf:Group>
      <cdf:TestResult start-time="2016-07-20T11:59:59" version="1" test-system="cpe:/a:spawar:scc:4.1" end-time="2016-07-20T12:00:50" id="U_Microsoft_DotNet_Framework_4_V1R4_STIG_SCAP_1-1_Benchmark-xccdf.xml---MAC-2_Classified-1">
            <cdf:benchmark href="U_Microsoft_DotNet_Framework_4_V1R4_STIG_SCAP_1-1_Benchmark-xccdf.xml"></cdf:benchmark>
            <cdf:organization>SPAWAR Systems Center Atlantic</cdf:organization>
            <cdf:identity privileged="true" authenticated="true">CCSAdmin</cdf:identity>
            <cdf:profile idref="MAC-2_Classified"></cdf:profile>
            <cdf:target>hostname</cdf:target>
            <cdf:target-address>192.168.1.000</cdf:target-address>
            <cdf:target-facts>
                  <cdf:fact name="urn:scap:fact:asset:identifier:host_name" type="string">hostname</cdf:fact>
                  <cdf:fact name="urn:scap:fact:asset:identifier:domain" type="string">.net</cdf:fact>
                  <cdf:fact name="urn:scap:fact:asset:identifier:fqdn" type="string">hostname.net</cdf:fact>
                  <cdf:fact name="urn:scap:fact:asset:identifier:os_name" type="string">Windows 7 Enterprise</cdf:fact>
                  <cdf:fact name="urn:scap:fact:asset:identifier:os_service_pack" type="string">Service Pack 1</cdf:fact>
                  <cdf:fact name="urn:scap:fact:asset:identifier:ipv4" type="string">192.168.1.000</cdf:fact>
            </cdf:target-facts>
            <cdf:platform idref="cpe:/a:microsoft:.net_framework:4.0"></cdf:platform>
            <cdf:rule-result version="APPNET0031" time="2016-07-20T11:59:59" idref="SV-7438r2_rule" weight="10.0" severity="medium">
                  <cdf:result>pass</cdf:result>
                  <cdf:check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
                        <cdf:check-content-ref href="U_Microsoft_DotNet_Framework_4_V1R4_STIG_SCAP_1-1_Benchmark-oval.xml" name="oval:mil.disa.fso.dotnet:def:2"></cdf:check-content-ref>
                  </cdf:check>
             </cdf:rule-result>
            <cdf:rule-result version="APPNET0046" time="2016-07-20T11:59:59" idref="SV-7444r3_rule" weight="10.0" severity="medium">
                  <cdf:result>fail</cdf:result>
                  <cdf:fix id="F-12602r12_fix"></cdf:fix>
                  <cdf:check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
                        <cdf:check-content-ref href="U_Microsoft_DotNet_Framework_4_V1R4_STIG_SCAP_1-1_Benchmark-oval.xml" name="oval:mil.disa.fso.dotnet:def:15"></cdf:check-content-ref>
                  </cdf:check>
            </cdf:rule-result>
      </cdf:TestResult>
</cdf:Benchmark>
```

I changed the queries and now both look like this:

```
var findingDetails = from f in element.Elements(ns + "Group")
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     idrefStatus = (string)"",
                                     result = (string)"",
                                     dateTime = (string)"",
                                     testID = (string)f.Attribute("id").Value,
                                     title = (string)f.Element(ns + "title"),
                                     idref = (string)f.Element(ns + "Rule").Attribute("id").Value,
                                     severity = (string)f.Element(ns + "Rule").Attribute("severity").Value,
                                     description = (string)f.Element(ns + "Rule").Element(ns + "description"),
                                     fixText = (string)f.Element(ns + "Rule").Element(ns + "fixtext")                                         
                                 };
            var getStatus = from gs in element.Descendants(ns + "rule-result")
                            select new
                            {
                                idrefStatus = (string)gs.Attribute("idref").Value,
                                result = (string)gs.Element(ns + "result"),
                                dateTime = (string)gs.Attribute("time"),
                                testID = (string)"",
                                title = (string)"",
                                idref = (string)"",
                                severity = (string)"",
                                description = (string)"",
                                fixText = (string)""
                            };

 var combined = findingDetails.Concat(getStatus);
```

But now the output looks like this

```
foreach (var cf in combined)
{
     Console.WriteLine(cf.idref + ", " + cf.result);
}

SV-7438r2_rule, 
SV-7444r3_rule, 
SV-40966r1_rule, 
SV-41075r1_rule, 
, pass
, fail
, pass
, pass
```

Whereas, I'm trying to get something like this:

```
SV-7438r2_rule, pass
SV-7444r3_rule, fail
SV-40966r1_rule, pass
SV-41075r1_rule, pass
```

Comment: types do not match ... how should they be concatenated except by casting the sequences to `object` or `dynamic`? please read up: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx *Because the Equals and GetHashCode methods on anonymous types are defined in terms of the Equals and GetHashCode methods of the properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if all their properties are equal.*

Comment: Are you trying to merge them rather than concatenating them? You can't concatenate two collections of different types.

Comment: It is certainly possible to concat collections of anonymous types, but only if *they have all the same fields* (types and names). Yours do not. How would you even expect to concatenate them? What would you expect the result to be?

Comment: @AntP, I considered a `.Merge()` but it doesn't come up in intellisense for `findingDetails`...

Comment: @Chris - maybe if you explain the motivation behind what you're trying to do we can help

Comment: @Chris what are you actually trying to do though? It looks like you're trying to create a list of two different types of object, which you can't do.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Because I'm pretty sure you aren't looking for a concatenation at all but some kind of join. But there's not enough context. What are you originally starting with (XML or HTML perhaps?) and what are you trying to get to?

Comment: @Chris the problem you have is that `concat` joins two lists, so if you have `[{ Foo: "Bar" }, { Foo: "Baz"}]` and `[{ X: "A" }, { X: "B"}]` you get `[{ Foo: "Bar" }, { Foo: "Baz"}, { X: "A" }, { X: "B"}]`, which doesn't make sense. Are you trying to get `[{ Foo: "Bar", X: "A" }, { Foo: "Baz", X: "B" }]`?

Comment: @GiladGreen What I'm trying to get is a var with that has everything from findingDetails + getStatus.result and getStatus.dateTime, in one place. This why I only have to iterate over one foreach() loop to access all of the values instead of using a nested foreach() loop.

Comment: I suspect you are working with XML, so include that structure in your question. I assume that the status parts are descendants of each element  with the details, and so it should be possible to get it with one linq query.

Comment: @Chris that is still ambiguous - can you demonstrate with example input/output sets?

Comment: @Chris - Question is what will it help to have a list containing a mixture of 2 types of anonymous types? What do you want to do with it after concating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your expected output (*"Whereas, I'm trying to get something like this:..."*) and data you added it seems like what you are looking for is a `join` and not to `concat` the lists (concat will give you n*m records)

This is what it seems you are looking for:

```
 XNamespace ns = "http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1";
 var findingDetails = (from f in XDocument.Load("data.xml").Descendants(ns + "Group")
                       let rule = f.Element(ns + "Rule")
                       select new
                       {
                          testID = (string)f.Attribute("id").Value,
                          title = (string)f.Element(ns + "title"),
                          idref = (string)rule.Attribute("id").Value,
                          severity = (string)rule.Attribute("severity").Value,
                          description = (string)rule.Element(ns + "description"),
                          fixText = (string)rule.Element(ns + "fixtext")
                       }).ToList();
 var getStatus = (from gs in XDocument.Load("data.xml").Descendants(ns + "rule-result")
                  select new
                  {
                     idrefStatus = (string)gs.Attribute("idref").Value,
                     result = (string)gs.Element(ns + "result"),
                     dateTime = (string)gs.Attribute("time"),
                  }).ToList();

 var result = (from d in findingDetails
               join f in getStatus on d.idref equals f.idrefStatus
               select new { d, f }).ToList();
```

If you might have `Group`s that do not have a matching `rule-result` then use `left join` instead

Comment: Gilad, Thank you! Again. Been a busy work learning all these things.

Comment: @Chris - Glad to be of help :)

Comment: You could optimize that a little to avoid repeatedly looking up `Rule` by doing something like `let rule = f.Element(ns + "Rule")` and then `idref = (string)rule.Attribute("id").Value`

Answer (score 1):

You can concat two anonymous types if they are declared with exactly the same properties.

You can't concat two different types, but you can cast them to `object` and then concat:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<string> strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };

ints.Cast<object>().Concat( strings.Cast<object>() );
```